# How much time in advance should users be informed of an upcoming maintenance on app?

Tags: mobile-application, messages

I'm desiging the UX on how to handle planned maintenance of a travel booking app. During this time frame, some services won't able available. I've decided that there will be messaging in the app as well as using push notifications.

My question is, how much in advance should users be informed of upcoming maintenance on the app? what should I consider for this time window? will it be a fixed time or will it be based on the services that would be affected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose a time that makes the users remember it.
If you inform them one week earlier, what are the chances they will remember whats going on when the maintenance is happening?

I'd say a shorter timeframe is much better (the day before the maintenance for example).

I would also recommend to send out an e-mail in addition to the push notifications (which some wont get) and the inapp message (which some wont see if they don't open the app).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how much the outage impacts users. From [Atlassian's blog](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/statuspage/scheduled-maintenance-message-examples-inspiration):

> Larger impacts call for longer lead time and more frequent updates
> before the maintenance. For small updates with no expected impact on
> users, one announcement message is usually enough. As the impact goes
> up, consider adding a reminder update right before the
> maintenance.[...]
>
> You don’t want updates so far in advance that users forget about them.
> In general, anything longer than a week of advance notice will need a
> reminder closer to the actual downtime. The further in advance your
> initial announcement, the more reminder updates you should schedule
> in. Consider multiple reminders and longer lead times for cases when
> users’ critical workflow will be interrupted and cases where you need
> them to take some action (like change a password or install new
> software).